# Incorrect display of LinearGradientBrush in IOS

Tags: c#, android, ios, maui

the problem is the display of LinearGradientBrush on the button, in Android it is correct, in iOS it is not

```
<Button Text="Войти" >
    <Button.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#DA8BFF" Offset="0.1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#839BFF" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Photo:[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLSnj.png),
[IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StM8s.jpg)

I tried to set sizes, add them to different containers